# Right place to detect browser and show/hide a div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show a div (using `ng-if` or `ng-show/hide`) if the user opens the page in a certain browser (in this case, chrome/chormium), and I'm not really sure where is the best place.

The javascript code looks like this: `/chrome/i.test( navigator.userAgent )`, but where is the best place to place it? In a filter? In a controller? In a directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below detailed browser detection script

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

I will suggest you to use "Directive" or "Filter"

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/sCCPb/3/)</kbd>

**Below is the filter example code:**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('checkBrowser', function(){

    return function(){

        return /chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
    }
})
```

**Template Code:**

```
<div ng-show="{{''|checkBrowser}}">Hello</div>
```

Comment: I already know how to detect the browser. I was looking for an example how to implement it.

Comment: using filter for this is overkill. This should be done in controller or directive. In this example the application will be checking it's user agent several times per **digest cycle**. How often does the `navigator.userAgent` change?...

Answer (score 2):

You could assign your condition to a scoped variable inside the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.isChrome = /chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
});
```

Then inside your view:

```
<div data-ng-show="isChrome">You're running Chrome!</div>
```

---

If you need a variable that's available to any controller, use a Service:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).factory('UAService', function() {
    return {
        isChrome: /chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
    };
});
```

Then from a page-level controller (i.e., one assigned to a top-level element such as `<body>`) or any other controller, inject your service:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'UAService', function( $scope, UAService ) {
    $scope.UAService = UAService;
});
```

Your service would now be accessible from any scope within the scope created by your page-level controller:

```
<div data-ng-show="UAService.isChrome">You're running Chrome!</div>
```

Comment: What if that div doesn't belong to any controller?

Comment: But this just falls back to a controller. What if I really haven't binded that div to any controller at all?

Comment: The `<div>` isn't bound to a controller, so you'll have to clarify what you mean by that. It exists in a scope which may or may not have access to ancestor scopes.